# A proof of linear dependence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The above is the question and the following is my attempt. But my tutor told me I cannot use y1'/y2'=dy1/dy2.
So is there any other way?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $g:= \frac{y_2}{y_1}.$ Then $g'=\frac{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2}=$ on $I$, hence $g$ is constant on $I.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\left(\frac{y_2(x)}{y_1(x)}\right)'=\frac{y_2'(x)y_1(x)-y_2(x)y'_1(x)}{y_1^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ an interval s.t. $y_1(x),y_2(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$.
$$W(x)=0\iff \frac{y'_1(x)}{y_1(x)}=\frac{y'_2(x)}{y_2(x)}\iff y_1(x)=Cy_2(x).$$

What else ?